# Excel time dd/hh/mm conversion to minutes only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-conversion

How do I convert turn around time written in an Excel cell as (0D/1H/6), meaning 0 days, 1 hour and 6 minutes to minutes only in another or adjacent Excel cell. I would like to automate that to make the conversion easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using some string functions. The code below calculates the minutes, given a cell (A1 in this case) with a string formatted the way you specified:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND("D/";A1)-1))*24*60 + VALUE(MID(A1;FIND("D/";A1)+2;FIND("H/";A1)-FIND("D/";A1)-2))*60 + VALUE(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("H/";A1)-1))
```

For instance, in your case "0D/1H/6" gives 66.

Comment: Please could you send me your email to help me with this small problem. I am not a programmer, but med. Tech and need this help. I can send you the excel sheet to see. Thanks

Comment: or contact me at gamcollab@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

As I dont think thats a format Excel natively understands I would use a VBA formula for this.

Alt+F11, Insert -> Module & add

```
Public Function TOMINS(value As String) As Long
    Dim parts() As String: parts = Split(value, "/")
    If (UBound(parts) = 2) Then
        TOMINS = Val(parts(0)) * 1440
        TOMINS = TOMINS + Val(parts(1)) * 60
        TOMINS = TOMINS + Val(parts(2))
    End If
End Function
```

Then if the value is in A1 & you want the minutes in B1, make B1  `=TOMINS(A1)`